# What color is this PNG?

Tags: png

This: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23437045/33275828-c96e8810-d3a4-11e7-9e36-f8fed85b6203.png

That's what QuickLook shows:

[image]

This is what Preview shows:

[image]

This is what Firefox shows (ignore the borders):

[image]

What color is that PNG?

Is this another "blue-black white-gold dress mystery"?

BONUS: This is what your browser shows

[image]

Comment: Preview & QuickLook show black, Photoshop won't even open it, says bad format.

Comment: Looks broken. eom says it's 1216x729 at 100% zoom regardless of what size the window is, and isn't showing the checkered background that it would for a transparent image.

Answer (score 1):

This png doesn't have any color. This is a transparent png.